# Empty body error on post request in python script

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make a post request to an API endpoint with python and requests.
The endpoint requires a token. I get the token from the endpoint just fine.

When making a post request to the second endpoint Validation Error stating that body is empty.

```
import requests

url = "https://authz.dinero.dk/dineroapi/oauth/token"
payload = 'grant_type=password&username=****&password=****'
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ****'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
r =response.json()
token = r['access_token']

url = "https://api.dinero.dk/v1/257403/contacts"
payload = {}
payload["Name"]  = "Test Name"
payload["CountryKey"] = "DK"
payload["IsPerson"] = "true"

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data = payload)
print(response.text)
```

This is the error I get:

> > {"code":42,"message":"Validation Error","validationErrors":{"Body":"The body was empty"},"languageSpecificMessages":[{"property":"message","message":"Der er fejl i de angivne data"},{"property":"Body","message":"The body was empty"}],"errorMessageList":[{"Code":"Body","Message":"The body was empty"}]}

Here is the same code taken from postman. It works fine.

```
import requests
url = "https://api.dinero.dk/v1/257403/contacts"
payload = "{\r\n  \"Name\": \"Test Name\",\r\n  \"CountryKey\": \"DK\",\r\n  \"IsPerson\": true\r\n}"
print(payload)
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ****'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

I hope someone can explain why my code isn't working.

Comment: You might need to first dump the `payload` to a JSON string (`json.dumps(payload)`) instead of passing the dictionary. At least thats the difference I can spot in the two snippets.

Comment: Your postman example has the payload as a JSON string, while your first example has it as a dict. You could try passing the dict as the json= param to requests.post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requests has a json= param you could use:

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Docs [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.post).

Answer (score 0):

In your second call, you want to json dump the payload:

```
import json

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Postman has already serialised the payload as a json formatted string. You can do the same with `json.dumps()`.